# ODBC driver connection string error

Tags: node.js, odbc

This is a general question that I can't seem to find any specific answer to. I am using a node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc

The module says to install a ODBC driver for the specified database and also have a properly configured odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini.

I am also using docker to run my node script.

My question is on my docker container, do I install each driver for the database? And then on the database server I have to configure the odbc.ini? Or on my node server I set this up? Or does it already come pre configured on some databases?

I keep getting the error: "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified"

Which I am guessing since I probably don't have the driver setup in my node container and the odbc.ini properly setup on my database server.

I am currently testing on a mysql database but want to be able to connect to any ODBC database.

Here is a link to setup mysql on ubuntu:

http://www.kaffeetalk.de/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-with-unixodbc-under-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 0):

`odbc.ini` contains DSN (Data Source Name) definitions, which are based on drivers registered in the `odbcinst.ini`, both found along with the drivers themselves on the ODBC data consuming host/environment (here, your `docker` container).  These configuration files are typically (and optimally) respectively targeted by `$ODBCINI` and `$ODBCINSTINI` environment variables, but sometimes found at default locations like `/etc/odbc.ini` or `~/.odbc.ini`.

You might look at some documentation, like the [ODBC spec on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft-open-database-connectivity-odbc), or [developer guidance on iODBC.org](http://www.iodbc.org/).  Do be sure to use ODBC's DBMS-agnostic SQL syntax for your queries, and not the DBMS-specific dialect for MySQL (or any other DBMS)!